# Disable select option if input is certain day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I disable a `select` `option` field if day is a Saturday?

I have one `input` and one `select`.

```
<input type="text" name="date">11/15/2016

<select>
    <option value="car">Car</option>
    <option value="boat">Boat</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
if(???) {
   $("option[value='boat']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

What should i put in the if statement if the `input` `date` is a Saturday?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var today = new Date('2016-11-15');
if(today.getDay() == 6) {//6 is saturday
    ...// disable the option value
}
```

Comment: how can i convert the date `11/15/2016` to `2016-11-15` format?

Comment: That kind of date parsing does not work in all browsers, FYI.

Comment: You can pass it directly with '11/15/2016'

Comment: Thought you should check for very older browser support. thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to support older browsers anymore. [Microsoft no longer supports browsers older than IE11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support).

Comment: That's good, I hate older browsers and hope some day every browser should work the same way :)

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a date object using selected value.

```
var selectedDate = new Date("11/15/2016");

// Use the get day method that will give you the day of the week.

if(selecteddate.getDay() === 6) {
     // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [**`Date.prototype.getUTCDay()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay)

  > The getUTCDay() method returns the day of the week in the specified
  >   date according to universal time, where 0 represents Sunday.
- [**Date Instance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) *`new Date(dateString)`*

  > Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment
  >   in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
  >   milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.
- [**`prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()` when dealing with boolean properties.

```js
var $dateInput = $("#dateInput"),
  $option = $("option[value='boat']");

$dateInput.on("change", function() {
  var date = new Date($dateInput.val());
  if (date.getUTCDay() === 6) {
    $option.prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $option.prop("disabled", false);
  }
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date.getUTCDay());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="date" id="dateInput">

<select>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
  <option value="boat">Boat</option>
</select>
```